# Checking whether values are Upper case or lower case

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to build a function in q/kdb+ that can detect whether the string passed to the function is Upper case (True) OR lower case (false)

I have done several attempts but I'm constantly hitting a road block
Here's my function, would appreciate the help. TIA

```
isAllCaps: {[input] if[input = lower; show 0b; show 1b]}
```

The above function basically takes an input as specified. It then checks from the if statement whether it is lower, if it is lower then it should return a false(`0b`), if not then return a true (`1b`). Really struggling with something so simple here. I'm just getting the following error:

```
evaluation error:

type

  [1]  isAllCaps:{[input] if[input = lower; show 0b; show 1b]}
                                   ^

  [0]  isAllCaps"a"
```

I have also tried other methods but only certain inputs were coming out to be successful.
For instance:

```
isAllCaps: {[x] if[ x = upper type 10h; show 1b; show 0b]}
```

This equates to if x is upper type string, show true, else show false. Again, getting a type error. Idk why? All the tests are in strings i.e., "John_Citizen" etc. etc.

**EDIT**
Tried this but I'm getting 2 outputs.

```
isAllCaps: {[L] if[L = lower L; show 0b; show 1b] } Am I missing something?
```

Comment: isAllCaps: {[L] if[L = lower L; show 0b]; show 1b }

Seems to be giving better results but in the case of a lower char, it sprouts out 0 and 1

Comment: It seems to work with this now but doesn't work on strings with more than one character

isAllCaps:{[L] if[L = lower L; show 0b] if[L = upper L; show 1b]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
isAllCaps: {[L] show L~upper L};
```

It shows `1b` if string is uppercase, and `0b` otherwise.

There are 2 mistakes in you code

1. `~` should be used to compare strings. `=` does character-wise comparison. I.e. `"aa"~"aa"` gives `1b`, but `"aa"="aa"` gives `11b`
2. Use `if-else`, instead of `if`. See [10.1.1 Basic Conditional Evaluation](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/10_Execution_Control/#1011-basic-conditional-evaluation) for more details

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, the code that you've given me works! How would I use the if-else? I checked it out on the main page however, got a bit confused :|

Comment: The [`show`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/show/) displays the result as well as returning it; could well be omitted.

Comment: The [`if`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/if/) control word is best reserved for side effects, such as signalling an error. Where a result is required, better to use the ternary conditional [Cond](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cond/), which returns a result. But in this case the test is the required result and can simply be returned – implicitly without the need for `show`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the in-built uppercase alphabet `.Q.A` to achieve what you want:

```
{all x in .Q.A}
```

This lambda will return `1b` if the input string consists only of capital letters and false otherwise.

Comment: Appreciate the logic but won't work on strings that are like "AAA_123" with numbers and all. But otherwise, good stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Start by removing some misapprehensions.

1. [`lower`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/lower/) returns the lower case of its argument.
2. [`show`](https://code.kx.com./q/ref/show/) displays and returns its result. You can use it as you have to ensure the function’s result is printed on the console, but it is not required as, for example `return` would be in JavaScript.
3. If you have a boolean as the result of a test, that can just be your result.
4. Compare strings for equality using [Match](https://code.kx.com/q/match/) `~` rather than [Equals](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/comparison/#six-comparison-operators)

That said, two strategies: test for lower-case chars [`.Q.a`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qa-lower-case-alphabet), or convert to upper case and see if there is a difference.

```
q){not any x in .Q.a}"AAA_123"
1b
q){not any x in .Q.a}"AaA_123"
0b
```

The second strategy could hardly be simpler to write:

```
q){x~upper x}"AaA_123"
0b
q){x~upper x}"AAA_123"
1b
```

Together with the [Apply](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/) `.` operator, the [Zen monks](https://community.kx.com/t5/Community-Blogs/Meet-the-Zen-monks/ba-p/11604) construction gives you fast ‘point-free’ code – no need for a lambda:

```
q).[~] 1 upper\"AaA_123"
0b
q).[~] 1 upper\"AAA_123"
1b
```